# SSL Certificate management with Windows DSC

Tags: dsc

I have a third-party issued certificate that I need to ensure is running on all targets in a given domain. Is there a way to ensure this certificate is installed by way of DSC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are taling about Powershell:

There is currently no built-in way to do this in DSC. I wrote a custom resource for my organization that installs a certificate from a PFX. I used the Cert: PSDrive, Import-PfxCertificate cmdlet and secured credentials in DSC (for the PFX password).

This is now live in Microsoft's resources! The xPfxImport resource is in the xCertificate module v1.1 (and later presumably).

Comment: Let me know more details, thanks